# JQuerymobile and Bartender Tabbar - individual icons

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm quite new to JQM and CSS so I am sorry if this is an easy question...

I've been playing around with the Bartender Tabbar (http://www.stokkers.mobi/valuables/bartender.html) and JQM. The Bartender tabbar comes with an example sprite of menu icons. I would like to replace these with individual icons from a library, such as glyphish.

I'm not sure what sections of the Bartender CSS files I need to edit to make them load individual icons...any help would be much appreciated.

I think I need to edit the section below (from Bartender.css):

```
/* ============= SEPERATE CSS-SPRITES  ======================= */

/*   7b. SEPERATE */

/*   REGULAR  */


.soloSprite li a .ui-btn-inner
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: static;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: none;
    background: url("sprite_lo-res.png") no-repeat; 
    background-size: 300px 44px; 
    -o-background-size: 300px 44px;
    -webkit-background-size: 300px 44px;
    -moz-background-size: 300px 44px;
    -ms-background-size: 300px 44px;    
}

.soloSprite li a[data-icon="features"] span:only-child 
{
    background-position:    0px 0px
}

.soloSprite li a[data-icon="brands"] span:only-child
{
    background-position:  -60px 0px
}

.soloSprite li a[data-icon="fees"] span:only-child
{
    background-position:  -30px 0px
}

.soloSprite li a[data-icon="contact"] span:only-child
{
    background-position:  -90px 0px
}

.soloSprite li a[data-icon="about"] span:only-child
{
    background-position: -120px 0px
}


.soloSprite .ui-icon::before
{
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorStr=#40ffffff,EndColorStr=#12ffffff);zoom: 1;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255,.15)), to(rgba(255,255,255,.0)));
    background-image:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 48.5%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100% ); 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 48.5%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100% ); 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 48.5%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100% ); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 48.5%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100% );
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 48.5%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100% );    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I received a response from the creator of Bartender...There is no easy to do this without creating your own icon set using the standard template he provides.