# ios tab bar with bartender.css How do I set icons?

Tags: html, ios, css, jquery-mobile, mobile-webkit

I am attempting to use bartender.css in a project I am making for fun. I desire to replace the default icons with my own icons, yet can't seem to find how to do so. There is an unresolved stackoverflow about it here also: [JQuerymobile and Bartender Tabbar - individual icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383067/jquerymobile-and-bartender-tabbar-individual-icons) but I feel that it should be asked again as many things with the plugin seem to have changed in the past year or so. In the example, it shows five different icons. Yet I can't find where in the css they need to be changed. I believe the icon Urls go somewhere in this part of the css:

```
/* ============= SEPERATE CSS-SPRITES  ======================= */
/*   7b. SEPERATE */
/*   REGULAR  */
.soloSprite li a .ui-btn-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    position: static;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: none;
    background: url("sprite_lo-res.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 300px 44px;
    -o-background-size: 300px 44px;
    -webkit-background-size: 300px 44px;
    -moz-background-size: 300px 44px;
    -ms-background-size: 300px 44px;
}
.soloSprite li a[data-icon="features"] span:only-child { background-position: 0px 0px }
.soloSprite li a[data-icon="brands"] span:only-child { background-position: -60px 0px }
.soloSprite li a[data-icon="fees"] span:only-child { background-position: -30px 0px }
.soloSprite li a[data-icon="contact"] span:only-child { background-position: -90px 0px }
.soloSprite li a[data-icon="about"] span:only-child { background-position: -120px 0px }
.soloSprite .ui-icon::before {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorStr=#40ffffff,EndColorStr=#12ffffff);
    zoom: 1;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255,.15)), to(rgba(255,255,255,.0)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 48.5%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100% );
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 48.5%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 48.5%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100% );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 48.5%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100% );
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.25) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 48.5%, rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100% );
}
```

**Update:** I have set up a JsFiddle. Any help is appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/excUq/

Comment: its better to replicate this in a fiddle. Anyway try overriding `.ui-icon`.

Comment: not so easy... I wrote bartender. The problem is you to get the exact IOS look and feel you need to mask the icon over variing backgrounds. Since mask effects are not supported cross-browser (and especially not on old IE), the only way to get the effect is to "cut out" the icons from a blank background. The github repo should have sample files (plain background, cut-out). If you are familiar with photoshop or inkscape and svg it's faily simple. If you have problems, please file an issue on [Git](https://github.com/frequent/bartender). I will try to update and provide some instructions